# Linux getaddrinfo not working with .local domains

Tags: domain-name-system, getaddrinfo

I'm connected by PPTP VPN to another network, mainly a windows network.  Running Ubuntu 16.04.1, freshly installed.

Most of the things I would like to connect to are on a .local domain.  I find that any application that does a getaddrinfo during the connection phase to the .local domain will fail:

Remmina, for example, gives this error:

**tcp_connect: getaddrinfo (Name or service not known)
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure**

I set up one workstation in DNS on both a .local and a .com domain and they both resolve fine:

```
rduz@henry:~$ nslookup bidsk0127.redacted.local
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   bidsk0127.redacted.local
Address: 172.16.5.155

rduz@henry:~$ nslookup bidsk0127.redacted.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   bidsk0127.redacted.com
Address: 172.16.5.155
```

I can connect fine to the .com name, no getaddrinfo error.  I cannot connect to the .local, it shows the getaddrinfo error.

In the old days, on SLES as I recall, we would update /etc/host.conf to have a line that said 'mdns off' to get .local resolution to work.  man host.conf doesn't show that as a valid option anymore.

Is there some way to fix things up so that the getaddrinfo call can correctly resolve a .local name?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More googling and I found the answer.  In my case, I don't want mdns, so I updated /etc/nsswitch.conf as follows:

```
root@henry:/etc# diff nsswitch.conf.orig nsswitch.conf
12c12
< hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
---
> hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: With my limited knowledge of `nsswitch.conf` I would have expected `files mdns4_minimal dns` to be what you were looking for. Any reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment from way back in December.  I don't know but it looks like a reasonable thing to try.  I'll do so if I get a moment.

Comment: I can confirm that `files mdns4_minimal dns` works.